# Add column sum to table

Tags: r

Data structure is:

```
Company        Marital
a              single
a              married
b              widow
c              married
b              single
```

I'm using `table(df$Company,df$Marital)`, but I want to have a column that shows the row total, such as the following:

```
            a     b    c    Total
married     50    20   5    75
single      10    10   10   30
widow       5     50   0    55
```

Is there a different table function that provides a row sum append option?

Comment: @BlakeS. An option using `data.table` as the title says `dcast.data.table(setDT(df)[, n:=.GRP, Company], Company~Marital, length, value.var='n')[,Total:= Reduce(`+`, .SD), .SDcols=2:4][]`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You could use `cbind` and `rowSums` afterwards:

```
tab <- table(df$Company,df$Marital)
tab <- cbind(tab, Total = rowSums(tab))
```

You can also use the built-in `addmargins` function:

```
tab <- addmargins(table(df$Company,df$Marital), 2)
```

(The `2` means to add a sum column, but not a sum row- you can omit it and you'll get both).

Comment: Thanks.  Are there any existing table functions that do this automatically?  Would prefer to avoid the second step if possible.

Answer (score 16):

You can use `addmargins`

```
x <- table(df$Company,df$Marital)
addmargins(x)         # option 1
ftable(addmargins(x)) # option 2
```

Answer (score 6):

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- tribble(
        ~status,      ~a,    ~b,  ~c,
        "married",     50,    20,   5,
        "single",      10,    10,  10,
        "widow",       5,     50,   0
        )

df %>% 
  mutate(Total_Row = rowSums(.[2:4]))
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   status      a     b     c Total_Row
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 married 50.0   20.0  5.00      75.0
#> 2 single  10.0   10.0 10.0       30.0
#> 3 widow    5.00  50.0  0         55.0

df %>% 
  mutate(Total_Row = select(., 2:4) %>% rowSums())
#> # A tibble: 3 x 5
#>   status      a     b     c Total_Row
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
#> 1 married 50.0   20.0  5.00      75.0
#> 2 single  10.0   10.0 10.0       30.0
#> 3 widow    5.00  50.0  0         55.0
```

Answer (score 5):

The `tabyl` function from the janitor package does exactly that.  With your data:

```
library(janitor)
dat %>%
  tabyl(Marital, Company) %>%
  adorn_totals("col")

 Marital a b c Total
 married 1 0 1     2
  single 1 1 0     2
   widow 0 1 0     1
```

*Self-promotion disclosure: I wrote and maintain this package.*  Posting this answer as the question asks about alternative approaches to table() that support adding totals - which is precisely what tabyl() does.

Comment: Tabyl is great, and I heartily recommend it.  It plays very, very well with pipes, and adds counts and percentages.