# add sum after last row, for some columns

Tags: r

I would like to print a table with sums, but only for certain columns.
Let's say for this example only column 2 and 3, while I would like to print the entire table (with sums for only 2 columns) and maintaining the original structure of the table.

```
x <- data.frame(
  fruit = c("apple", "orange", "banana"),
  amount = c("10", "5", "4"),
  price = c(2.5, 2, 1.5),
  taste = c("great", "super", "nice"))
x`
```

Could you please help me with this?

Comment: Could you provide an example of the expected output?

Answer (score 2):

To help you in the right direction. Would do it this way:

```
x$amount <- as.numeric(x$amount)
x["Total" ,] <- colSums(x[c("amount", "price")])
print(x, na.print = "", row.names = FALSE)
```

Output:

```
   fruit amount price taste
   apple      1   2.5 great
  orange      3   2.0 super
  banana      2   1.5  nice
              6   6.0
```

Comment: Great Fierr, this is way better than I found out. Thanks a lot. Do you also know how to use row.names = false and if possible leave out the NA's?

Comment: Would use print(x, na.print = "", row.names = FALSE) to show empty fields and to hide the rownumbers. Note: this does not change the underlying content.

Comment: Yes, that's close, I think I forgot to  mention, that I like the word "Total". If this can be placed in column fruit it would be totally perfect.

Comment: Its probably possible with some additional tweaking, but I wouldn't go that way if I were you. If you really need a specific format, think about putting the output in Excel for example and doing the tweaking there.

Comment: I found out that the janitor package can make this work (with the word Total). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969616/add-column-sum-to-table/48371963