# How to create a function and add results as a column?

Tags: r, function, dataframe

If I have a dataframe:

```
A B C
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

and I want to add a column D that is the sum of columns A,B,C how do I write a function that will do that and add the result as column D to the data frame?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add column sum to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27969616/add-column-sum-to-table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is with mutate from the library dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4, c = 3:5)

df = df %>%
       mutate(d = a + b + c)
```

Comment: Thank you! I Think the mutate function is what I need.

Answer (score 2):

One way is with `rowSums`:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:3, b = 2:4, c = 3:5)
df$d <- rowSums(df)
```